# HighStock graph for non date records

Tags: highcharts

In highstock chart,

1. Is it possible to achieve the bar chart with range selector at the yaxis instead of xaxis.
2. Is it possible to have the non-date values (i.e some customer names) as x axis(if xaxis as range selector) and alphabets as the range selector?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Not yet, vote [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2364547-add-navigation-bar-for-y-axis-in-highstock).
2) Yes, using Highcharts instead: http://jsfiddle.net/b826C/1/